# Search method in a DAO like SQL's LIKE

Tags: java, oop, dao

I'm doing my own DAO classes using plain JDBC as an exercice.

Now, does something like an SQL LIKE fit into the DAO pattern ?

What I'd like to do is support a search feature which matches a field against a string. Is there another approach that is more suitable to OOP ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function with a good comment can fit your need :)

```
class MyDAO {
  /* Search user which name contains searchName */
  public List<User> searchUserByName(String searchName) {
    String sql = "select * from USERS where USERNAME like '%" + searchName + "%'";
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();    
    // Execute sql, 
    // open ResultSet, 
    // iterate it and for every ResultRow's row convert to object User
    // Add converted object User to users
    // Free resource
    return users; 
  }
}
```

This is just an idea, you need transaction management, connection supplier and so on

Comment: So there is no "heresy" in adding such a method :p . Thanks for erasing my doubts.

Comment: sql injection detected

Comment: It is only a trace, not the implementation :/

Comment: Done. Added this method in the DAO and will elaborate on it :)